# Conditional login redirect in Django

Tags: django, redirect, authentication

I know about `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` and I know about

```
<form action="?next={{ next|default:"/foo" }}" method="post">
```

in django-registration's login.html template. Here's what I want to happen:

- If a user logs in from the homepage,
  redirect them to a URL that contains
  their username (/lists/[username]).
- If a user logs in from any other
  page, return them to the page they
  were viewing.

The way twitter.com handles this is to simply make the homepage go away for logged in users. I would consider doing that, and it would be pretty easy to solve, but my homepage still has useful stuff on it and I'm not sure I want it to go away for authenticated users. I'd rather redirect them.

I was thinking I could do a conditional in settings.py where `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` is referenced, but the request object is not available in settings (so I can't access request.user.username to build the redirect). And obviously, I can't do it in django-registration's "default" parameter in the template because the username isn't known before login.

What's the correct/best way to solve this? Thanks.

**Update**: Based on S. Lott's suggestion below, this is what I ended up using (in the homepage view):

```
if request.user.is_authenticated() and not request.session.get('homepage_redir'): 
    request.session['homepage_redir'] = True
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('list_view',args=[request.user.username]))
```

On the first login from homepage, the user is redirected to their personal page and a session variable is set. On subsequent requests for the homepage, the redirect does not occur (because the session var is detected). Code for redirecting logins from any other page is not affected.

Comment: What about redirecting to a pseudo-page that knows what to do next (has access to `request`) ?

Comment: Tomasz - That sounds similar to Manoj's response below (but he posted it in answer format rather than as a comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If a user logs in from any other page,
>   return them to the page they were
>   viewing.

This is what Django does anyway.

Check for a session and redirect to a login properly, using Django's already provided functions.

> If a user logs in from the homepage,
>   redirect them to a URL that contains
>   their username (/lists/[username]).

This is what view functions are for.

If the request session is empty, they just logged in.  Set a flag in the session and return a redirect to the desired page.  Be sure to use the `reverse` function -- do not code the URL anywhere in your applications.  Ever.

Comment: Thanks, but @login_required means the view can't be seen by non-auth users. It doesn't accommodate a situation where you want a page to be public, but they have to log in if they want to add a comment.

Comment: As for altering the view function, I prefer not to alter/fork django-registration. Unless you know of a way to do this with django-registration without forking it.

Comment: "I prefer not to alter/fork django-registration"?  What?  Are you trying to modify the behavior of the Django registration app?  Please **update** your question to specifically say this.  http://code.google.com/p/django-registration/ How do you propose to change the behavior without altering?  That seems like a contradiction.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you. Since my question refers to django-registration, and because you said "This is what view functions are for," I thought you meant I should alter the view(s) in django-registration.

Comment: Now I realize that what you mean is that I can just detect is_authenticated() in the homepage view and redirect them (though that will effectively make the homepage become inaccessible to authenticated users, which I had hoped to avoid).

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: this is hackish.

Do you mind doing two redirects? This way your `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` can be a view that identifies the logged in user and redirects the request to the appropriate home page for the user (`/lists/username/`)

This will cost you two redirects instead of the usual one. First, post login to the view, next from the view to the home page.

Comment: Hmm, that is a bit hackish, but you're right, it would work. Let me ponder that.