# Django redirect the right way?

Tags: python, django, url-routing, redirect

I have a similar question to this -
[Conditional login redirect in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842075/conditional-login-redirect-in-django/4389601#4389601)

But I couldn't understand how to achieve the result from answers there.

I am relatively new to django. I reused this code from somewhere, which redirects the user to login page. But after login I always get to the start/home page of the user. I want them to see the page they really requested, and not the user homepage all the time. Can you tell me what and where I can make the change, it should be where I am using 'redirect' function. I probably should save some session variable and do it but not quite getting the starting point. any thoughts?

Below is the code -

```
def view_or_basicauth(view, request, test_func, realm = "", *args, **kwargs):
    if test_func(request.user): # Already logged in, just return the view.
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

    # They are not logged in. See if they provided login credentials
    if 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' in request.META:
        auth = request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'].split()
        if len(auth) == 2:
            # NOTE: We are only support basic authentication for now.
            if auth[0].lower() == "basic":
                uname, passwd = base64.b64decode(auth[1]).split(':')
                user = authenticate(username=uname, password=passwd)
                if user is not None:
                    if user.is_active:
                        login(request, user)
                        request.user = user
                        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

    # Either they did not provide an authorization header or something in the authorization attempt  failed. Send a 401 back to them to ask them to authenticate.
    key = request.path.split('/')
    if len(key) > 1:
        base_url = request.get_host()
        return redirect( 'https://' + base_url + '/login/')

    s = '401 Unauthorized'
    response = HttpResponse(s)
    response.status_code = 401
    response['Content-Length'] = '%d' % len(s)
    response['WWW-Authenticate'] = 'Basic realm="%s"' % realm
    return response
```

Comment: You should not normally use basic authentication.  Unless encrypted by SSL, credentials are transferred on *every* request in *clear text*.  This is far too vulnerable for most sites.  `django.contrib.auth` (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/) provides a session based solution that is ideal for the majority of users, or use django-openid (https://github.com/simonw/django-openid)

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty straight forward:

Add a GET parameter to to your redirect line so that your login view knows where your user is coming from. It can be anything, but I'm using `"?redirect=myurl"`.

In your login view: check for the existence of that key (`redirect`) in GET upon successful login. If it exists, redirect to the value.

First modify your redirect line:

```
# add a GET parameter to your redirect line that is the current page
return redirect( 'https://' + base_url + '/login/?redirect=%s' % request.path )
```

Then in your login view, just check for your variable in GET and redirect to that value if it exists.

```
# modify the login view to redirect to the specified url
def login(request):
    # login magic here.

    if login_successful:
        redirect = request.GET.get('redirect') # get url

        if redirect:
            # redirect if a url was specified
            return http.HttpResponseRedirect(redirect) 

        # otherwise redirect to some default
        return http.HttpResponseRedirect('/account/home/')
    # ... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the URL as a GET parameter in the redirect, and have the redirect target redirect them back after they've entered their credentials.

Comment: I am sorry, but I couldn't understand your response as I am a new django user. Where should I pass the url? and how would I redirect it back? thank you!