# Conditionaly redirect users after login

Tags: python, django

I have looked at both [Django -- Conditional Login Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824004/django-conditional-login-redirect) and [Conditional login redirect in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842075/conditional-login-redirect-in-django) and neither address my current issue.

What I want to do is check a property of the user after they have successfully logged in. If the property is in a good state send them directly to the page specified by the `next` URL argument, otherwise send them to fix the property and then forward them to the `next` page.

So far I have succeeded in sending the user on to `next` after they have fixed the property, but I can't conditionally redirect after login.

I know I can set the `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`, but that only applies if there is no value in `next`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I needed to do was create a view based on `LoginView` and check the property in the `get_redirect_url` method.

In `views.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from django.shortcuts import resolve_url

def passes_test(a_value):
    #test the value here
    return False  

class PropertyCheckLoginView(LoginView):
  def get_redirect_url(self):
    redirect_url = super().get_redirect_url()
    user = self.request.user
    if not passes_test(user.property_to_test):
      redirect_url = resolve_url('url_to_fixing_form/?next='+redirect_url)
    return redirect_url
```

Then in `urls.py` add or change the `login` url:

```
urlpatterns = [
  ...,
  url(r'^login/$', PropertyCheckLoginView.as_view(),  name='login'),
  ...,
]
```